# Vim: Jumping to if endif in fortran

Tags: vim, fortran

For C or C++, `[{` or `]}` can be used in `vim` to jump to the beginning or end of the code block. Is there a similar shortcut to jump for a code block between a `if` and `endif` in `vim` for Fortran?

The issue is due to not-so-well formatted code, involving a lot of nested `if's` making the readability difficult. Any solutions for such case?

Answer (score 12):

The built-in but disabled-by-default matchit plugin should help you with that.

Add this line to your `vimrc`:

```
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

After you restarted Vim you should be able to press `%` to jump from `if` to `endif` and back.

Comment: You may also need to add the line `filetype plugin on` to your `vimrc` before `runtime macros/matchit.vim`

Comment: Thanks. However, the command confuses with the macros ( `#else` in between). Any solutions for this?

Comment: @Ross : The feature works only macros (#ifdefs). How do extend to normal `if` statements in code?

Comment: @Ross: Could you respond to above comments?

Comment: I'm still learning new vim tricks after all these years. This works for me as described in the answer.

Comment: That's the problem. Treating those things as tricks.