# Jump to matching "done" while editing bash script in vi

Tags: bash, vi

In vi, the % key can be used to jump to a matching opening or closing parenthesis, square bracket or a curly brace.

Could it also be used to jump between matching "do" and "done" in a bash loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not ["vi"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) as such.  vim does that.
There is a script `matchit.vim` which can do this:

- The script is documented in the vim wiki page *[Moving to matching braces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_to_matching_braces)*.
- It part of the vim distribution, but is not installed (in your `~/.vim/plugin` directory) by default.  See the vim help for [matchit-install](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#matchit-install) for details.
- Once installed, it has to be enabled, e.g., (see *[matchit.zip : extended % matching for HTML, LaTeX, and many other languages](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39)*):

  `filetype plugin on`

  in your vimrc file.

For further reading:

- *[Vim: Jumping to if endif in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585697/vim-jumping-to-if-endif-in-fortran/32587056#32587056)* uses simply `runtime macros/matchit.vim` rather than the two-part install from the vim wiki.
- *[Matchit not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281459/matchit-not-working/11758264#11758264)* has several answers, some disagreeing.

The `runtime macros/matchit.vim` line in `~/.vimrc` did not make matchit.vim work in my quick test; the procedure in `matchit-install`, plus the `filetype` line did work.  As usual, your configuration may differ.

I maintain (and of course use) [vi-like-emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html), and wrote comparable functionality for that editor using a different approach (see discussion of ["fences"](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile-hlp.html#mode-fence-if) in documentation).  In a quick test, I see that `matchit.vim` does not know about the syntax for case-values in a shell case statement.  So there is some room for improvement.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!